# Get value from a variable

Tags: typescript

I have a problem. I have a const `data`. And inside of this there are two values `prediction` and `probability`. What is the best option to get the value of this both?

```js
type ML = {
    prediction: string;
    probability: number;
};

type GetUsersResponse = {
    data: ML[];
};


private async something(txt: string) {
        try {
            // ️ const data: GetUsersResponse
            const { data, status } = await axios.post<GetUsersResponse>(
                'http://127.0.0.1:5000/prediction',
                {
                    "text": txt
                },
            );

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));



            // ️ "response status is: 200"
            console.log('response status is: ', status);

            return data

        } catch (error) {
            if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
                console.log('error message: ', error.message);
                return error.message;
            } else {
                console.log('unexpected error: ', error);
                return 'An unexpected error occurred';
            }
        }
    }

const data = something("This is a string")
// data looks like
// data = {
           "prediction": "Class 1",
           "probability": 0.612535596
           }
```

What I tried

```
data[0].prediction

TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'string | GetUsersResponse'.   Property '0' does not exist on type 'string | GetUsersResponse'.

data.prediction
TS2339: Property 'prediction' does not exist on type 'string | GetUsersResponse'.   Property 'prediction' does not exist on type 'string'.

data.data[0].probability
TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'string | GetUsersResponse'.   Property 'data' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Comment: What is `something`'s type ? In other words what does your `test()` method return ?

Comment: @antoniom I updated the code. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your `something` function can return `GetUserResponse` or `string`, so you need to check first the type of the `data`.

```
if (typeof data == 'string') {
    // do something when error
} else {
    data.data[0].prediction
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But with that I got `cause: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: I check with `if (Array.isArray(data.data)) { // do your code } else {console.log('no array'}` -> it says `no array`

Comment: Try to log the `data` inside `else` block and see the structure of it.